# AS3 regex - how to match 2 consecutive matches multiple times?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I have the following regex, which will match all the `<br>` and `<br />` tags in a string:

```
/<br[\s|\/]*>/gi
```

I actually want to match every set of two consecutive tags, with valid matches being:

```
<br><br>
<br/><br>
<br><br/>
<br/><br/>
(and all variations with a space before the slash)
```

Obviously I can just double up the expression to `/<br[\s|\/]*><br[\s|\/]*>/gi`, but is there a shorter way of taking the first expression and saying "this, but twice"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

`/(<br[\s|\/]*>){2}/gi`